# Eclipse Unhandled event loop exception with Birt

Tags: eclipse, soap, alfresco, birt, cmis

I'm getting unhandled event loop exception when trying to create Birt data set to get data from Web Service data source.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
  at org.apache.xerces.dom.NamedNodeMapImpl.findNamePoint(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xerces.dom.NamedNodeMapImpl.getNamedItem(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.ws.util.WSDLAdvisor.getSignificantNode(WSDLAdvisor.java:783)
  at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.ws.util.WSDLAdvisor.getSignificantNode(WSDLAdvisor.java:790)
  at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.ws.util.WSDLAdvisor.getSignificantNode(WSDLAdvisor.java:790)
```

I'm trying to send soap request from SoapUI and get normal responce
Response:

```
<S:Body>
      <ns2:queryResponse xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/" xmlns:ns2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/">
         <ns2:objects>
            <ns2:objects>
               <properties>
                  <propertyId queryName="cmis:objectTypeId" displayName="Object Type Id" localName="objectTypeId" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectTypeId">
                     <value>D:test:MyClass</value>
                  </propertyId>
               </properties>
            </ns2:objects>
            <ns2:objects>
               <properties>
                  <propertyId queryName="cmis:objectTypeId" displayName="Object Type Id" localName="objectTypeId" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectTypeId">
                     <value>D:test:MyClass</value>
                  </propertyId>
               </properties>
            </ns2:objects>
            <ns2:objects>
               <properties>
                  <propertyId queryName="cmis:objectTypeId" displayName="Object Type Id" localName="objectTypeId" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectTypeId">
                     <value>D:test:MyClass</value>
                  </propertyId>
               </properties>
            </ns2:objects>
            <ns2:hasMoreItems>false</ns2:hasMoreItems>
            <ns2:numItems>3</ns2:numItems>
         </ns2:objects>
      </ns2:queryResponse>
   </S:Body>
```

My settings for Birt data set:

1. Use schema from responce
2. Select Sample SOAP responce message is #1 and empty
3. Row Mapping: /S:Envelope/S:Body/ns2:queryResponse/ns2:objects
4. Column Mapping: /ns2:objects/properties/propertyId/value

When I click on "Show Sample Data" it's displays normal and I see values but when I click on "Finish" button it's crash.

Can you help me, where I'm wrong or this is birt issue, maybe someone can found workaround?

Comment: I posted a bug to eclipse https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=425282

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem here.

Got this working by changing the binding of our JAX-WS WebService from RPC to Document.
Anyway, if you can't change your WebService, you are still stuck with this problem.

Anyway, upvoted the Eclipse Bug as it's a very buggy situation.